# Where'd our community bulletin board go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, community-bulletin-board

Our community bulletin board seems to have disappeared from the site. What happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an error with a new check added to the code recently.  It's been corrected and deployed.

The community bulletin is back in its rightful place in the sidebar. (:

Comment: Thanks for the quick resolution!